# TMs on the same nodemanager which leads to high pressure on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

we have a 100-node hadoop cluster. Currently I write a Flink App to write many files on HDFS by BucktingSink. When I run Flink App on yarn I found that all task managers is distributed on the same nodemanager which means all subtasks is running on this node. It opens many file descriptors on the datanode of this busy node. (I think flink filesystem connector connect to local datanode in precedence) This leads to high pressure on that node which easily fails the job.

Any good idea to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Yarn scheduling problem. Please take a look at [Yarn's capacity scheduler](https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/) which allows you to schedule containers on nodes based on the available capacity. Moreover you could tell Yarn to also consider [virtual cores](https://blog.cloudera.com/managing-cpu-resources-in-your-hadoop-yarn-clusters/) for scheduling. This allows to define a different resource dimension compared to memory only.